# Is there a way in SPSS syntax to add a name variable to a file path to be able to export output into excel format with the corresponding name?

Tags: excel, file, path, export, spss

I need to export and save SPSS output into Excel format for more than 100 people. I am trying to avoid renaming the files manually. Like in Python, I tried to add the full-name variable into the file path, but I get this error every time:

> *The procedure cannot access a file with the given file specification: C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSSST~1\full_name_concat.xlsx. The file specification
> is either syntactically invalid, specifies an invalid drive or
> directory, specifies a protected directory, specifies a protected
> file, or specifies a non-sharable file.*

This is the part of the syntax that I tried to achieve it:

```
STRING full_name_concat (A255).
COMPUTE full_name_concat = CONCAT (' "C:\Users\itenis\Documents\ARPS\FOR CREATING PROFILES\OUTPUT ', RTRIM(full_name), '.xlsx" ').
  
OUTPUT EXPORT
  /CONTENTS EXPORT=VISIBLE LAYERS=VISIBLE MODELVIEWS=VISIBLE
   /XLSX DOCUMENTFILE='full_name_concat'
     OPERATION=CREATEFILE
     LOCATION=STARTCELL('a1')  NOTESCAPTIONS=NO.
```

I spent hours searching for answers before I decided  to take the risk and ask here.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK this won't work because the syntax will not interpret the column name and use the values in it's operations. There are two ways to make this happen - one is through SPSS macro ([this is a nice site](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-macros/) to look it up). The other way is through `write` command - the following code writes a new syntax that creates a new command for each value of `full_name`:

```
STRING full_name_concat (A255).
COMPUTE full_name_concat = CONCAT (' "C:\Users\itenis\Documents\ARPS\FOR CREATING PROFILES\OUTPUT ', RTRIM(full_name), '.xlsx" ').

write out="your path\do named outputs.sps" 
       /"OUTPUT EXPORT"
       /"/CONTENTS EXPORT=VISIBLE LAYERS=VISIBLE MODELVIEWS=VISIBLE"
       /"/XLSX DOCUMENTFILE=", full_name_concat
       /"OPERATION=CREATEFILE"
       /"LOCATION=STARTCELL('a1')  NOTESCAPTIONS=NO." .

exe.
insert file="your path\do named outputs.sps".
```